# why does "Ein kleiner fehler" become "Eines kleinen Fehler"?

Tags: accusative

I was writing that I have "fixed a small error", and when I translated it to German it said:

"Behebung eines kleinen Fehler"

I understand that Fehler is maskulin, therefore "kleinen" is used in Akkusative form, but why did "ein" change to "eines"?

Thanks

Comment: “When I translated it” - did you use a tool, website or app?

Comment: yes, sadly google translate

Comment: I don’t see it: https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=de&text=I%20have%20fixed%20a%20small%20error.&op=translate

Comment: Note that this phrase is incorrect, as it should be in the genitive case here, which would make it "Fehlers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's not the accusative, but the genitive (*Wessen Behebung?* or *Behebung wessen?*).
That's the reason why *ein* changed into *eines* (note that *Fehler* needs to transform into *Fehlers* for this => "*Behebung eines kleinen Fehlers*").

Note, that this sentence uses the **Nominalstil** (nominal style), it transforms the verb (*beheben*) into a noun (*Behebung*). That's because there was no subject given in the original sentence. A correct version would be "*I fixed a small error*", it would literally translate into "*Ich behob einen kleinen Fehler*".

An alternative to translate "*fixed a small error*", would be "*kleinen Fehler behoben*", which is not a full sentence for its own, but your original english sentence is neither. It's only suitable for the use in lists, like changelogs.

Comment: Thanks. Is "Ich behob" used more in writing than in speaking? So If I said it, it would be "ich habe einen kleinen Fehler behoben"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In spoken language, perfect is more often used instead of the usual past tense.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.
Regarding the nominal style, has it therefore translated it as "the fix(ing) of a small error", therefore "a small error" is in the genetiv form?  If so, why is only the "eines" affected and not the "klein(en)". I would have assumed eines kleines Fehler would be the genetiv form?

Comment: How is it that this (otherwise correct) answer completely ignores the grammar mistake in the original translation, as the genitive of "Fehler" is actually "Fehlers"?

Comment: O.R.Mapper, I included your hint in my answer. James, I'd say that's because klein only describes the manner of the mistake. And yes, "the fixing of a small error" would be the literal counterpart for the nominal styled sentence.

Comment: The interrogative pronoun is *wessen*, no matter if preceding or following the noun. I fixed that and implemented standard question word order that might be easier to understand for language learners. Second minor edit: it's the subject (agens) that's missing in the original sentence.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus ... that won't help lerners, I'm afraid :) You need to be born speaking German to infer that you have to ask the the *wessen*-question in this case. Sure, you can learn that *wessen* and genitive are coupled, but then you don't have the piece of information you need to come to that question (you could as well come to *wen* or *wem*, erroneously, since you don't have it in your mind).

Comment: @c.p. I didn't add it, I corrected *wessen**s*** because it had an *s* too much.